# Matrix demonstration $A^k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}     7 & 4\\     -9 & -5 \end{bmatrix}$ $\in \mathcal{M2\times2}\, (\mathbb{R}) $

Show that $A^k = \begin{bmatrix}     1+6k & 4k\\     -9k & 1-6k \end{bmatrix} $
for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: What have you tried so far? What approach do you think will work here?

Comment: Have you tried proof by induction?

Comment: yes I thought about the proof by induction but i got lost in the process, I don't know which way is the best, honestly.

Comment: Can you start by computing $A^kA$ and simplifying the result? Shows us your work.

Comment: yes the result is this matrix I think $\begin{bmatrix}
    7+6k & 4+4k\\
    -9-9k & -5-6k
\end{bmatrix} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a simple induction on $k$; it is clear that for $k = 1$,

$A^1 = A = \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 4 \\ -9 & -5 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 + 6 \cdot 1 & 4 \cdot 1 \\ -9 \cdot 1 & 1 - 6 \cdot 1 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 1$

then assuming that for *some* $k$

$A^k = \begin{bmatrix} 1 + 6 \cdot k & 4 \cdot k \\ -9 \cdot k & 1 - 6 \cdot k \end{bmatrix}, \tag 2$

we find

$A^{k + 1} = A^kA = \begin{bmatrix} 1 + 6 \cdot k & 4 \cdot k \\ -9 \cdot k & 1 - 6 \cdot k \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 4 \\ -9 & -5 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 7 + 42k - 36k & 4 + 24k - 20k \\ -63k - 9 + 54k & -36k  - 5 + 30k \end{bmatrix}$
$= \begin{bmatrix} 7 + 6k & 4 + 4k \\ -9 -9k & - 5 -6k \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 + 6(k + 1) & 4(k + 1) \\ -9(k + 1) & 1 - 6(k + 1) \end{bmatrix}, \tag 3$

which is simply (2) with $k$ replaced by $k + 1$; we thus infer the formula (2) holds for all $k \ge 1$, as desired. $OE\Delta$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N = A-I$ and observe that $N^2=0$. Since $N$ and $I$ commute, we can expand via the binomial theorem: $$A^k = (I+N)^k = I+\binom k1N+\binom k2N^2+\dots = I+kN.$$

How did I hit upon this decomposition? I computed that $1$ was the only eigenvalue of $A$, but the only diagonalizable $2\times2$ matrices with repeated eigenvalues are multiples of the identity, so $A$ splits into the sum of the identity and a nilpotent matrix. That is, $$A = P\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}P^{-1} = I + P\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$$ for some invertible matrix $P$.

Comment: Very nice indeed, ***endorsed, +1!!!***